# Should I use AND or OR when combining two negative conditions?

Tags: go, if-statement

Three vehicle types are `Car`, `Motorcycle` and `Bicycle`. Three statuses are `Available`, `Reserved` and `Sold`.

I want to print the information of all vehicles that are *not* `Car` **and** are *not* `Sold`, i.e. sold cars should not be printed. In other words, print information of everything that is `Motorcycle` or `Bicycle`, with any status among `Available`, `Reserved` and `Sold`. If it is a `Car`, still print as long as it is `Available` or `Reserved`.

The vehicles are:

1. Car - Sold
2. Car - Available
3. Car - Reserved
4. Bicycle - Sold
5. Bicycle - Available
6. Bicycle - Reserved
7. Motorcycle - Sold
8. Motorcycle - Available
9. Motorcycle - Reserved

I expect the following code to print everything except number 1 (Car - Sold)

My code:

```
for _, v := range results {
    if v.Type != "Car" && v.Status != "Sold" {  // && does not work but || works
        resp = append(resp, &VehicleInfo {
            ID: v.Id,
            Brand: v.Brand,
            Type: v.Type,
            Status: v.Sold,
        })
    }
}

fmt.Println(resp)
```

When I use `AND (&&)`, `Println` result is very strange, it outputs 5, 6, 8, 9. However, when I switch to `OR (||)`, it prints exactly what I want, which is everything except 1 (sold car), which is a list of all `Motorcycle` (any status), all `Bicycle` (any status) and all `Car` that is either `Available` or `Reserved`.

What is the problem here? I thought using `AND (&&)` was the right answer, but it is not.

Comment: useful reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws. What you want is `not(A and B)` (none of cars that are sold). That is equivalent to `(not A) or (not B)`. `(not A) and (not B)` is `not(A or B)`, which, in your case, means: "nothing sold and also none of the cars"

Comment: When you explain it to a person you said: _sold cars should not be printed_. Your code is likely to be most easily understood if you write it this way, i.e., `!(car && sold)` (which, by DeMorgan's law, is the same as `!car || !sold`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem statement is... unclear. The statement

> I want to print the information of all vehicles that are not `Car` **and** are not `Sold`,...

But the remainder of the problem statement:

> ... i.e. sold cars should not be printed. In other words, print information of everything that is Motorcycle or Bicycle, with any status among Available, Reserved and Sold. If it is a Car, still print as long as it is Available or Reserved.

Indicates that you want to filter out (exclude) cars that have been sold.

The easiest way is something like this:

```
for _, v := range results {
  isSoldCar := v.Type == "Car" && v.Status == "Sold"

  if isSoldCar {
    continue
  }

  resp = append(resp, &VehicleInfo {
    ID: v.Id,
    Brand: v.Brand,
    Type: v.Type,
    Status: v.Sold,
  })

}
```

or this:

```
for _, v := range results {
  isSoldCar := v.Type == "Car" && v.Status == "Sold"

  if !isSoldCar {
    resp = append(resp, &VehicleInfo {
      ID: v.Id,
      Brand: v.Brand,
      Type: v.Type,
      Status: v.Sold,
    })
  }

}
```